# Row Numbers Auto Added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to coding and doing some tinkering. Trying to create a score keeper for family games. Stuck at getting rows to be numbered automatically. I can add rows dynamically, and have the entered information automatically added up in the "total" row (bottom row). But can't get row numbers starting with the second row. Here is code so far [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChaseO/cznjetLn/2/)`link`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var gameRounds = [1, 2];

$(document).on("keyup", ".add", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".add").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $("#sum").text(sum);
});

var newRound = $('#newRound');

newRound.click(function(){
    $('.totals').before(
     "<tr>",
      "<td class='round'></td>",
      "<td class='p1'><input class='add' id='r1' type='number' name='r1'></td>",
     "</tr>"
     );

   console.log(gameRounds); 

  });
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
 width: 15%;
}

.p1 {
 background: lightblue;
}

/* .p2 {
  background: lime;
} */

/* .p3 {
  background: orange;
} */

.round {
 width: 3em;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="update">
  <thead>
    <th class="round">Round</th>
    <th class="p1">player1</th>
  </thead>
  <tr class="r1">
    <td class="round"></td>
    <td class="p1">
      <input class="add" id="r1" type="number" name="r1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="round"></td>
    <td class="p1">
      <input class="add" id="r2" type="number" name="r2">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tfoot class="totals">
    <td class="round">total</td>
    <td class="p1">
      <span id="sum"></span>
    </td>
  </tfoot>

</table>

<div class="btnStyle">
  <button id="newRound">New Round</button> 
</div>
```

Button and calculator don't work in jsfiddle, but work just fine in sublime and codepen.

Comment: Please include your logic with your question, rather than just linking to a paste site.  Not all users can access paste sites and if the paste site ever stops hosting your logic, the question will become significantly less useful to future readers who may have the same issue as you are having.

Comment: What exactly are you not getting numbered?

Comment: Just add jQuery on the JavaScript panel to get it working with JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

here's an example solution:

Add a new JS function:

```
  function nomerateRows(){
  var roundNum = 1;
  $('.round').each(function(x){
    $(this).html(roundNum++);
  });
};
```

Invoke it once on document ready and everytime you add a new row.

Here's the full example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lqzyw4u4/8/

Answer (score 0):

You're close!

Before talking about the code, your JSFiddle didn't work because you need to include the resource jQUery.

For your code you will need to keep a count of how many rows there are. Currently you have an array but in my opinion that is overkill for what you're doing and you won't need the data saved that way.

ex.

```
<tr class="r1">
    <td class="round">1</td>
    <td class="p1">
      <input class="add" id="r1" type="number" name="r1"></td>
  </tr>
```

Start by adding the row numbers into the already existing html. Then, modify your click function to increment how many rows there are. After that, add that count to that table column

```
newRound.click(function(){

    //Update how many rounds there are
    numGameRounds++;

    $('.totals').before(
        "<tr>",
        "<td class='round'>"+ numGameRounds +"</td>",
        "<td class='p1'><input class='add' id='r1' type='number' name='r1'></td>",
        "</tr>"
    );

    console.log(gameRounds); 

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cznjetLn/4/

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much, and also for the help with jsfiddle.